# Prevent * from bolding text when creating a headline

Tags: org-mode

When I start typing several stars to create a new headline, like `***`, emacs starts bolding some of them, making the first and the last invisible. This makes it hard to know what headline level I am at, because it bolds and unbolds them as I keep adding more `*`.

This did not use to happen before. Has anything changed?

How can I make `***` at the beginning of a line just behave like a literal `***`, but only for headlines?

Comment: I'm assuming you have `org-do-emphasis-faces` set to t. That's probably what changed for you. I see this too and I think it's a bug with `org-do-emphasis-faces`. Should be simple to fix it.

Comment: It's actually not a bug, and I think I agree with what Nicolas [said](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-11/msg00352.html): "It is something to be expected with a non-nil `org-hide-emphasis-markers`. `"***"` at the beginning of the line is really a bold asterisk, whereas `"*** "` is a headline."

Comment: @jagrg You're right. If you want, make that the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Ha. I didn't realise you'd posted the second answer two. I consider the first one the explanation (which I opted for, in the end).

Comment: I see. I updated the answer to reflect your preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was raised on the mailing list and the response was:

> It is something to be expected with a non-nil
>   `org-hide-emphasis-markers'. "***" at the beginning of the line is
>   really a bold asterisk, whereas "*** " is a headline.

Comment: Thanks! The real answer was: "[Y]ou have org-do-emphasis-faces set to t."